# I need help understanding this puzzle

Tags: tactics, beginner, puzzles

With White to play, I have trouble understanding what goes on in this puzzle. First of all, how exactly Kh1 is preferable to Kxh2? I know that Black can give checks after Kxh2, but there really is no mate threat anyway and White gets rid of a pawn that way. Also, why does Black follow up with Qe3, which leads to them losing a piece? Is there not a better move for them to play?

```
[fen "1r5k/1p5p/p5p1/2P1rRq1/P2Q4/8/1P5p/5RK1 w - - 0 2"]

1. Kh1 Qe3 2. Qxe5 Qxe5 3. Rxe5
```

Answer (score 3):

**1. Kxh2** allows Black a forcing sequence exchanging off the pieces and White loses his big advantage: **1... Qh6+ 2. Kg2** now Black can capture the Rook on f5 and force a trade of queens: **2... gxf5 3. Qxe5+ Qg7+**.